# Android Web App - If the connection is successful for url1, else url2?

Tags: java, android, web, webview, android-webview

I have a webview android app.
There are countries that block the main domain of the website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekTIR.jpg)
And I have a secondary link to open in these networks - countries.
note. Website blocking here, is not about malicious websites. Rather, some newspapers and websites do not contain any violations.
I use java
I need to use command

```
  String url1 = "htttps://domainone.com";
  String url2 = "htttps://domaintwo.com";
if
```

url1 - connection is successful {

```
webview.loadUrl(url1);
```

}

```
else {
    webview.loadUrl(url2);
}
```

or
If the error does not appear
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
{

```
    webview.loadUrl(url1);
```

}

```
else {
webview.loadUrl(url2);
}
```

need code showing the method with thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved

```
        if (errorCode != WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP
                &&
       errorCode != WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(Url1);
        } else {

            mWebView.loadUrl(Url2);
        }



}
```

Comment: formatting code is always helpful